# wx: validate() controls in a container stops after first invalid

Tags: python, c++, wxpython, wxwidgets

i am validating user input controls such as textboxes and dropdowns. The problem i have is, that the validation (the containers.Validate()) stops after finding the first invalid control. I expected it to validate all controls, before it returns. I want to display the user all invalid controls at once, not one by one. Is there a way to do so?

(using wx.WS_EX_VALIDATE_RECURSIVELY will propagate to the children, but only if no other control was invalid before)

**Edit:**
Instead of overwriting Validate() for every control, i decided to have a separate function, which iterates over all children and validates them. 
Note: This function will not be called by default `OnOK` event. To do so, the event handler must be rebound.

```
def ValidateRecursively(control):
    '''Validate this control and its children recursively''' 
    validator = control.GetValidator()
    # no validator -> valid
    isValid = validator.Validate(control) if validator else True
    for childControl in control.GetChildren():
        # only validate enabled controls
        if childControl.IsEnabled():
            isValid &= ValidateRecursively(childControl)
    return isValid
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to override `Validate()` in your dialog and iterate over all controls yourself without stopping at the first invalid one, like the base class implementation does.

Unfortunately you will probably need to duplicate the [code here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/src/common/wincmn.cpp#L2026) as there is no way to reuse it. On the bright side, you can use it almost as is with just changing the `return false` lines to remember the error instead and return it at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code base. I am developing with the python version of wx, so unfortunately i can not use the implementation straight away. It would be nice to just have another flag, to enable full validation of all child controls.

Just for understanding your suggestion, why override `TransferData{To,From}Window()` and not directly `Validate()` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right, you should indeed override `Validate()`, I'll update the original answer.